# Broken pipe during a subprocess stdin.write

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

I interact with a server that I use to tag sentences. This server is launched locally on port `2020`.

For example, if I send `Je mange des pâtes .` on port `2020` through the client used below, the server answers `Je_CL mange_V des_P pâtes_N ._.`, the result is always one line only, and always one line if my input is not empty.

I currently have to tag 9 568 files through this server. The first 9 483 files are tagged as expected. After that, the input stream seems closed / full / something else because I get an `IOError`, specifically a `Broken Pipe` error when I try to write on `stdin`.

When I skip the first 9 483 first files, the last ones are tagged without any issue, including the one causing the first error.

My server doesn't produce any error log indicating something fishy happened... Do I handle something incorrectly? Is it normal that the pipe fails after some time?

```
log = codecs.open('stanford-tagger.log', 'w', 'utf-8')
p1 = Popen(["java",
            "-cp", JAR,
            "edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTaggerServer",
            "-client",
            "-port", "2020"],
           stdin=PIPE,
           stdout=PIPE,
           stderr=log)

fhi = codecs.open(SUMMARY, 'r', 'utf-8') # a descriptor of the files to tag

for i, line in enumerate(fhi, 1):
    if i % 500:
        print "Tagged " + str(i) + " documents..."
    tokens = ... # a list of words, can be quite long
    try:
        p1.stdin.write(' '.join(tokens).encode('utf-8') + '\n')
    except IOError:
        print 'bouh, I failed ;(('
    result = p1.stdout.readline()
    # Here I do something with result...
fhi.close()
```

Comment: Well, the code looks a little dangerous - you're assuming that the result is always one line. Could also be the server running on the remote host enforcing some maximum limit to the total amount of data you can send in a single TCP connection. Could also be an issue in the Java client.

Comment: @Aya: I've edited to reflect the fact that I run the server locally (could there still be limitations on the total amount of data I can send? I really have no clue about those things). Plus, the answer is always one line, the problem doesn't come from there, I think. The Java doesn't produce any error even in debug mode, that's what puzzles me :( Thanks for the input!

Comment: It would very much depend on the client and server code, and how the client translates its stdin/stdout to/from TCP packets. If you're running the server locally, you could try eliminating the client from the equation, and have Python connect to the server directly.

Comment: I didn't want to manipulate sockets directly but you're right, it'd help debug. Thanks for the hint :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to my comments, I might suggest a few other changes...

```
for i, line in enumerate(fhi, 1):
    if i % 500:
        print "Tagged " + str(i) + " documents..."
    tokens = ... # a list of words, can be quite long
    try:
        s = ' '.join(tokens).encode('utf-8') + '\n'
        assert s.find('\n') == len(s) - 1       # Make sure there's only one CR in s
        p1.stdin.write(s)
        p1.stdin.flush()                        # Block until we're sure it's been sent
    except IOError:
        print 'bouh, I failed ;(('
    result = p1.stdout.readline()
    assert result                               # Make sure we got something back
    assert result.find('\n') == len(result) - 1 # Make sure there's only one CR in result
    # Here I do something with result...
fhi.close()
```

...but given there's also a client/server of which we know nothing about, there's a lot of places it could be going wrong.

Does it work if you dump all the queries into a single file, and then run it from the commandline with something like...

```
java .... < input > output
```

Comment: I'll investigate with the new elements you brought up. I'll report when I find something new :)

Comment: @Mog also note the warning in the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html): `Use communicate() rather than .stdin.write, .stdout.read or .stderr.read to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process.` although that would require a new call to `Popen` for each input line. Suffice it to say, even pipe-based IPC can be quite tricky. :)

Comment: Actually I'm going through this whole thing precisely to avoid calling Popen at each step (loads a jvm, x 9 000, it hurts). but yup it seems to be precisely the kind of problem I run into :-(